# Android custom view in cell

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter, android-custom-view

I have a `RecyclerView` inside my activity which shows 4 different cards of different type. One of that card is showing a calendar custom view from this library [WeekView](https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View/blob/develop/library/src/main/java/com/alamkanak/weekview/WeekView.java) . Everything shows ok until i start scrolling my view and the calendar card starts getting out of the screen bounds. The custom week view seems to be drawn over the toolbar layer causing the above effect shown in the image

[image: Before scroll]

[image: After scroll]

As you can see the cardview is scrolling correct but the custom week view is going above the toolbar layer.

In my `Adapter` i initialize the `WeekView` in my `ViewHolder`

```
calendarView = (WeekView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.todayView);
if (calendarView != null) {
            initializeCalendarView(calendarView);
        }


private void initializeCalendarView(WeekView mWeekView) {
    mWeekView.setOnEventClickListener(this);
    mWeekView.setMonthChangeListener(this);
    mWeekView.setEventLongPressListener(this);
    mWeekView.setEmptyViewLongPressListener(this);
    setupDateTimeInterpreter(false, mWeekView);
    mWeekView.goToToday();

    mWeekView.setColumnGap((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 8, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
    mWeekView.setTextSize((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
    mWeekView.setEventTextSize((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
}
```

And this is my `xml` for my `CardView`

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/doctorDashboardCalendar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="800dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin10"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="#e0e0e0">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/notes_icon_dark"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text18"
                android:fontFamily="@string/font_name_2"
                android:text="Calendar"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <*************************.WeekView
            android:id="@+id/todayView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="true"
            app:eventTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:textSize="12sp"
            app:hourHeight="30dp"
            app:headerColumnPadding="4dp"
            app:headerColumnTextColor="@color/toolbar_text"
            app:headerRowPadding="6dp"
            app:columnGap="4dp"
            app:noOfVisibleDays="1"
            app:headerRowBackgroundColor="@color/toolbar"
            app:dayBackgroundColor="#05000000"
            app:todayBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            app:headerColumnBackground="#ffffffff"
            app:todayHeaderTextColor="@color/accent"
            app:showNowLine="true"
            app:nowLineColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:enableScrolling="false"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: By any chance did you turn off clip children?  That's the only way I normally see something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Custom view :

```
android:margin_top="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

this will make a margin top at the size of the actionbar/toolbar which will make the scroll fixed to the correct size.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. If you comment code of the above format in the `WeekView` it works correct

```
canvas.clipRect(left, top, width, heigh, Region.Op.REPLACE);
```